# Navigate without redirect?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mojarra

I currently have a navigation-menu:

```
...
<p:menuitem id="id1" value="Page 1" action="home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" actionListener="#{homeBean.someMethod(1)}"/>
<p:menuitem id="id2" value="Page 2" action="other.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" actionListener="#{otherBean.someMethod(1)}"/>
```

Now I want to get rid of these redirects. So I tried the attribute url instead of action, but then the actionListener isn't called anymore.

How can I call a listener in this case

```
<p:menuitem id="id1" value="Page 1" url="home.jsf">
  ... here (or maybe somewhere else) should go the call to my listener ...
</p:menuitem>
```

Jonny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `p:menuItem` supports POST and GET. Which one of these is selected depends on the presence of the `url` attribute. A quote from the [PF documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html):

> This is decided by url attribute, if it is present menuitem does a GET request, if not parent form is posted.

If you want to invoke an action method on the server side you need to do a POST.  If you don't want the redirect, you need to return the navigation target as `String` from your action method:

```java
public String someAction() {
  ...
  return "home";
}
```

This will navigatio to `home.xhtml` if the action method has finished.

You can call this action method from your menu:

```
<p:menuitem id="id1" value="Page 1" action="#{someBean.someAction}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your help. This solved the case. One more thing: If I don't add **ajax="false"** I get the following error: _UI Layout Initialization Error. The center-pane element does not exist. The center-pane is a required element._ Any guess what is causing this?

Comment: Good to hear that it works. As to the second problem: Don't know, maybe something with your layout configuration (if you are using `p:layout`)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using p:layout. But its the same template and only the content changes. I'm puzzled. What exactly do you mean by _layout configuration_?

Comment: It seems to be related to the underlying jQuery layout. Not sure what is the reason. But using Google I found some people with the same problem. Maybe you find a solution there.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your help. I googled this already a while ago and again today, but no solution yet. I guess I'll have to skip this p:layout stuff, since its causing too much trouble (especially in IE 7).

Comment: Primefaces and IE7 are not the best friends.